# Proving that $f(t)=t(a-\frac{ab}{c/t+b})$ is bounded

Tags: calculus

How to prove the following function is bounded for $t \geq 0$

$f(t)=t(a-\frac{ab}{c/t+b})$

where $c,b>0$.

**My attempt**

When I take the second derivative, I see that the function is concave when $t \geq 0$. So, there can be one global maximum at most. I don't know if that can help.

Comment: Have you tried any specific values of $a$ and $b$? Can you conjecture what the bound might be based on the graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewriting $f$ as $$f(t) = t(a-\frac{ab}{c/t+b}) = t\frac{ac/t + ab - ab}{c/t + b} = \frac{ac}{c/t + b}$$
shows that $f$ is increasing in $t$. So you just need to take the limit as $t\to \infty$.